# html/javascript: using a variable as url for <a href>

Tags: javascript, html, url, variables

I developed a html page with a bit of javascript.
I have several  tags and after clicking a link one of them is dynamically assigned a background image. This url is stored in a global variable. So far so good.

```
var picture,thumb

function changeDivs(p)
{
     if (p!='') {
        picture = './images/p'+p+'.jpg'; // global url variable
        thumb = './thumbs/p'+p+'.jpg'; // global url variable
        var pic = "url("+thumb+")";
        document.getElementById("poster").style.backgroundImage = pic;
        }
}
```

I call the function like this:

```
<a href="javascript:changeDivs('2')">Link</a>
```

Now I want to make use of a thumbnailviewer script which needs to be accessed like this:

```
<a href="javascript: global variable" rel="thumbnail"> <!-- Of course this "javascript: global variable" should be a valid url: the stored 'picture' variable -->
        <div id="poster"> 
        </div>
    </a>
```

So I have stored the url in variable: picture

How can I access the thumbnailviewer script through `<a href>` AND use the variable. I don't know if the thumbnail script can be called through a function or how.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I removed your intro about hoping someone can help you. That's what we're all here for and that's why we're looking at your question, so you're in good hands. Welcome to stackoverflow! :D

Comment: where and how exactly are you gett the p in changeDivs(p)?

Comment: This is how I call the changeDivs function:            

<a href="javascript:changeDivs('1')">
 <img src="thumbs/p1.jpg" width="50px" height="70px" />
</a>

Comment: so, you have solved your issue?

Comment: No.. not really. Problem is, it's a bit complicated. I use maybe a dozen links to change the bg-img of a div tag in a function, but need that same info for use in a '<a href>' tag.

Thanks for the welcome btw :)

Comment: can you put up a jsfiddle @ http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: I'll look at it. It's new to me, so give me e minute :) 
Thanks btw.

Comment: BTW the page is viewable at www.brennfilm.com/temp/index.html
You can look at my code there.

Comment: You can pick the whole website here: http://www.brennfilm.com/brennfilm_2010.zip

Comment: Please take a look at my new answer.

Comment: Okay.. close. Now I want to click the div as a whole and open the image in a thumbnail viewer.

Comment: check my addition on your <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/62uNK/4/" rel="nofollow">jsfiddle</a>

Comment: what's your thumbnail viewer.

Comment: http://www.brennfilm.com/temp/script/thumbnailviewer.js

here's the site were it runs
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/thumbnail.htm

Comment: did i answer your posted question?

Comment: close. Now I want to click the div as a whole and open the image in a thumbnail viewer. I added some code at the end in the html box

Comment: try the new jsfiddle link in my answer.  please give rep/correct answer if this answers your question.

Comment: Doesn't work. Clicking the thumbnail doesn't change the image and the thumbnailviewer opens, but no picture. (it NEEDS the href url to open it - which is my variable). But this is exactly what I want. Now you know the problem :)
Thanks so far...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are attempting to achieve.  Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62uNK/7/).
When an `'<a href>'` is clicked an image becomes the background of `"<div id='poster'>"`

I replaced your pic's URL with your existing thumbnail url.  Please make sure your picture and thumb variable's URL exist.  Also, i set width and height of your poster's div.

To work with thumbnailviewer, try the new jsfiddle link please.  FYI, dynamicdrive blocked jsfiddle from accessing the js files.  Please try the code on your own project.

Comment: Doesn't work. The thumbnailviewer opens, but no picture. (it NEEDS the href url to open it - which is my variable). But now you know the problem :) Thanks so far

Comment: this might be the plugin's issue.  i had similar issue with dynamic loading after dom is ready VIA javascript with jQuery's NivoSlider.  i am not familiar w/ thumbnailviewer to know if this is true however.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Since it is 5 am here now... I'll hit the sack :) Thanks again.