# Discover IP octet and then make it a href URL?

Tags: javascript, variables, url, concatenation, href

Okay, so I've gone as far as I can go. First here are the prerequisites I cannot change:

- Windows platform
- Can only use IE 11

**My goal: Detect the client IP address, then place that variable into a URL on a web page. Basically, this link will take the user to that device's "home page."**

Since it is a Windows OS, I can use an ActiveX call just as longs as it is specific to a single function. In this case, the function is to get the client's IP address.

```
<script>
    var objLocator = new ActiveXObject("WbemScripting.SWBemLocator");
    var objService = objLocator.ConnectServer(".","root\\CIMV2");

    instances = objService.ExecQuery(
        "SELECT Caption, IPAddress, MACAddress FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"
    );

    e = new Enumerator(instances);

    var IPAddy = "";
    for(;!e.atEnd();e.moveNext()) {
        nic = e.item();

        if(nic.IPAddress!=null) {
            var ipArray = VBArray(nic.IPAddress).toArray();
            IPAddy = IPAddy + ipArray[0]+"<br>";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now that I have the IP address as 'IPAddy' I will strip it down to get the 4th octet - the 'ddd' of aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.

```
<script>
  var input = IPAddy;
  var split = input.split('.');
  var TPage = split[3];
</script>
```

Now the part I cannot get to work right. (I thought the answer was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356844/), but it didn't work for me.) I want to take the variable '*TPage*' and make it into a URL for the PC user.

In the body of the HTML file:

```
<div class="w3-bar-block w3-black">
  <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-blue" href="bodytest016.html">Start</a>
  <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-text-white" href="pages/' + TPage + '.html" target="bigWindow">Your Computer Information</a>
  <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-text-white" href="pages/links.html" target="bigWindow">Your Web Pages</a>
  <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-text-white" href="pages/help.html" target="_blank">Help</a>
</div>
```

I've checked that the variable scripts do work by adding a little section of the page to check my work:

```
<script>
    document.write(IPAddy);
    document.write(TPage);
</script>
```

At the end of the day, I want to open up the IE browser to the "start page." The page will then identify my IP address as 95.10.10.126 and I will be able to click on the link, "Your Computer Information," which should take me to ./pages/126.html.

So what am I doing wrong with: 
...href="pages/' + TPage + '.html" (the Your Computer Information link)? In IE, it looks like this: "file:///F:/pages/'+%20TPage%20+%20'.html"

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in `href="pages/' + TPage + '.html"`; you can't use a JavaScript variable directly in the HTML like that.

Instead, you first need to target the element. In my example, I do this with **[`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)**, though note that you will require an `id` attribute on the element in order to use that selector. Once selected, you need to change the `href` attribute. You can combine your fixed string with the JavaScript variable in this regard with some simple concatenation using `+`:

```js
var TPage = '127.0.0.1';
var link = document.getElementById('link');
link.href = "pages/" + TPage + ".html";
console.log(link);
```

```html
<a id="link">Your Computer Information</a>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML:

```
<a href="pages/' + TPage + '.html">Your Computer Information</a>
```

doesn't know anything about the JavaScript variable `TPage` which you have the last octet stored in, and instead assumes that you want the literal `' + TPage + '` to appear in the url. Since some of those aren't valid characters in the url, they get translated to the %-encoded string you're seeing.

What you probably want to do is have JavaScript set the url which that points to. There are many ways to do that.

Assuming that you want to keep your JavaScript separate from your HTML, one way to do that is as follows:

- add an `id` to the link in question
- change the `href` of the link in question to have a placeholder for the IP octet
- add some JavaScript code (at the bottom of the page, it must be below the link) which fixes up the url in the `href`.

It might look something like this:

```
<a id="info-link" href="pages/${IP_OCTET}.html">Your Computer Information</a>
<script>
    var link = document.getElementById('info-link');
    link.href = link.href.replace('${IP_OCTET}', TPage);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fantastic! Both answers are great.

From Obsidian Age's answer, I created this script:

```
<script>
  var input = IPAddy;
  var split = input.split('.');
  var TPage = split[3];
  var link = document.getElementById('link');
  link.href = "pages/" + TPage + ".html";
  console.log(link);
</script>
```

However, I needed PeterJCLaw's response to get it to work. I had to put that script at the bottom of the menu DIV object, just after the anchor tag links. Like this:

```
<div class="w3-bar-block w3-black">
  <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-blue" href="bodytest016.html">Start</a>
  <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-text-white" id="link" target="bigWindow">Your Computer Information</a>
  <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-text-white" href="pages/links.html" target="bigWindow">Your Web Pages</a>
  <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-text-white" href="pages/help.html" target="_blank">Help</a>
  <script>
      var input = IPAddy;
      var split = input.split('.');
      var TPage = split[3];
      var link = document.getElementById('link');
      link.href = "pages/" + TPage + ".html";
      console.log(link);
  </script>
</div>
```

Woo-hooo! Thank you both!